# Merging large no. of columns in Python

Tags: python, join, merge

I am new to Python so please bear with me. I have 30 individual columns in 30 data files which have around 1000 numbers in each of them. I want to make a grand table by joining all these columns in the form of a single table with 30 columns. I have tried functions `Merge()` and `Join()`.

Comment: hi welcome to SO. please post a snippet of your code to improve the quality of your post/question that way the community can better help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge single data column from multiple csv files into one with Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34767459/how-to-merge-single-data-column-from-multiple-csv-files-into-one-with-pandas)